# Knockout template add id to ul inside template

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following code:

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/a4uT7/)

I generate few rows and add them to a table. Foreach row I want to add a button which is a template.

Using it this way is not working :

```
<td data-bind="template: { name: 'userContext-template', data: id }"></td>
```

If i remove the `data: id` then it's working:

```
<td data-bind="template: { name: 'userContext-template' }"></td>
```

Any ideas what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `userContext-template` you have this line:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" data-bind="attr: { id: id }" role="menu">
```

If you pass the id as data to the template, ko will try to access id.id in this binding. Try replacing it with:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" data-bind="attr: { id: $data }" role="menu">
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4uT7/1/

Or pass the entire $data as data to the template, instead of passing just the id